# http-proxy-middleware not using path

Tags: node.js, http-proxy-middleware

Even when I use the sample provided:

```
var express = require('express');
var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var app = express();

app.use('/api', proxy({target: 'http://www.example.org', changeOrigin: true}));
app.listen(3000);
```

The output when I start the server is:

```
node prod-server.js
[HPM] Proxy created: /  ->  http://www.example.org
```

I am expecting:

```
node prod-server.js
[HPM] Proxy created: /api  ->  http://www.example.org
```

Comment: Have you gone to `/api` in your browser? It should be setup correctly.

Comment: Yes, it hangs for awhile then I get: Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:3000/api

Comment: Your going to `http://localhost:3000/api` in your browser and you get that error? I copied the exact code you have and worked as expected.

Comment: Correct. I'm using node 6.11.2, "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.4".

Comment: Did some more digging, looking like the http proxy is working but my websocket proxying is not.

Comment: Adding to the confusion, I made no changes but everything started working and websocket connection started upgrading... weird.

Comment: I'm having same issue...